# Tensorflow Keras doesn't work with ragged tensor input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm using Tensorflow 2.3.

If I use a normal tf tensor input, the example below works fine:

```
import tensorflow as tf
text_input = tf.keras.Input([None], dtype=tf.string, name="text_input", ragged=False)
predictions = tf.gather(text_input, 0, axis=-1)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input], outputs=[predictions])
model(tf.constant([['A1', 'A2', 'A3'], ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']]))

<tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=string, numpy=array([b'A1', b'B1'], dtype=object)>
```

However, if I change the input to a ragged tensor, I got an error while trying to create the model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
ragged_input = tf.keras.Input([None], dtype=tf.string, name="ragged_input", ragged=True)
padded_input = ragged_input.to_tensor('')
predictions = tf.gather(padded_input, 0, axis=-1)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[ragged_input], outputs=[predictions])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-201-9adaf4aae2b5> in <module>()
      3 padded_input = ragged_input.to_tensor('')
      4 predictions = tf.gather(padded_input, 0, axis=-1)
----> 5 model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[ragged_input], outputs=[predictions])

13 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     62     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError:  You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_38' with dtype int64 and shape [?]
     [[node Placeholder_38 (defined at <ipython-input-201-9adaf4aae2b5>:5) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_136790]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me because the `RaggedTensor` support for Keras isn't the best (see e.g. [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27170)). I'm not exactly sure what is causing it but the ragged conversion is failing for the placeholders.

If you can, it's probably best to use all `RaggedTensor` functionality *before* passing it as an input and setting `ragged=False`. This is not an issue if you only want to use it for convenient padding and if all graph operations are based on non-ragged tensors (which is the case for your example):

```
import tensorflow as tf
ragged_input = tf.keras.Input([None], dtype=tf.string, name="ragged_input", ragged=False)
# padded_input = ragged_input.to_tensor('')
predictions = tf.gather(ragged_input, 0, axis=-1)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[ragged_input], outputs=[predictions])
padded_input = tf.ragged.constant([['A1', 'A2'], ['B1', 'B2', 'B3']]).to_tensor('')
result = model(padded_input)
print(result)
# >>> tf.Tensor([b'A1' b'B1'], shape=(2,), dtype=string)
```

Answer (score -3):

You can try creating a `tf.keras.Sequential` model if you have single inputs and outputs.